# internal body is hollow blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, units

i made a body of the gun but blender is not showing the the internal  body it is hollow in inside have i done something wrong (blender v 2.8) 
the picture is

[image]

please tell the problem??? BLENDER

Comment: Welcome to Blender's StackExchange! It looks like you've just extruded the contours without adding faces at the front. What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Whatever you need inside you have to put it there as an object. I guess it goes for all kinds of 3D modeling software.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't model the interior of your model, there will be nothing there.  You can enter vertex/edge/face edit mode, select some verts and use hotkey 'H' to hide the selected verts and alt + 'H' to unhide them.  With verts hidden you can see inside your mode to add interior.

You can also add a modifer that will add 'thickness' to your mesh so there will be an interior.